# Inputting CountIfs function into loop

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I've been trying to create a script that will first delete all unnecessary rows and then insert a `COUNTIFS` function directly to the right.  I've error tested everything, and I know the problem is in the actually `COUNTIFS` formula, specifically when I'm trying to reference the current row. `"" = "" & .Cells(lrow, 1).Value`

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        With ActiveSheet.Range("B6:B1217")
         For lrow = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
             If .Cells(lrow, 1).Value = "0" Then
                .Rows(lrow).Delete
             Else
                 .Cells(lrow, 2).Value = Evaluate("CountIfs(Sheets("Jan").Range("A:A"), "" = "" & .Cells(lrow, 1).Value, Sheets("Jan").Range("F:F"), ">" & "0")")
            End If
         Next lrow
        End With
```

Comment: When using Evaluate you need to be passing it a string which would be a valid worksheet formula: you can't use it to evaluate VBA.

Comment: @Tim What would be the proper way to write this file?  I'm just trying to figure out how i can use a variable so that it will generate for every line.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```vb
Dim f
'one of these two...
f = "=COUNTIFS(A:A," & .Cells(lrow, 1).Value & ", F:F, "">0"")"
f = "=COUNTIFS(A:A,""" & .Cells(lrow, 1).Value & """, F:F, "">0"")"  

.Cells(lrow, 2).Value = Sheets("Jan").Evaluate(f)
```

Whether or not you need quotes around the inserted value in the formula depends on whether the value is numeric or not.